# retrieving data by sql and codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

when i use this sql the result of mem_name from the first table is repated a lot how can i fix it

```
    <?php     
    $sql="SELECT mc.mc_id,mc.mc_role,mc.mc_order,mc.mc_order IS NULL AS isnull, mem.*
                    FROM $this->memberCatsTableName mc, $this->tableName mem

                    WHERE mc.cat_id=$cat_id $where  AND mc.member_id=mem.mem_id or mem.mem_name='$mem_name'

                    ORDER BY isnull ASC, mc.mc_order ASC";

            $query = $this->db->query($sql);
            return $query->result_array();
?>
```

Comment: you should group by the query by mem_name

Comment: Ooh i didn't want to miss my points.. i am going to answer this question you have to accept and upvote it.. its my reward :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is modified query..

```
<?php     
    $sql="SELECT mc.mc_id,mc.mc_role,mc.mc_order,mc.mc_order IS NULL AS isnull, mem.*
                    FROM $this->memberCatsTableName mc, $this->tableName mem

                    WHERE mc.cat_id=$cat_id $where  AND mc.member_id=mem.mem_id or mem.mem_name='$mem_name' 

       Group by mem.mem_name 

                    ORDER BY isnull ASC, mc.mc_order ASC";

            $query = $this->db->query($sql);
            return $query->result_array();
?>
```

You can group by the query..

```
Or you can also specify the join criteria
```

Hope its helped.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify a join criteria.